# How to use notification_key using GCM?

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any GCM client and server php example which describes use of notification_key .Since my application needs push notification for user with multiple devices. But couldnot find any suitable example or way to implement this http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html.

Thanks,Please help.

Comment: You can look on simillar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560739/not-able-to-send-notification-to-a-group-using-notification-key-even-though-it-i/25183793#25183793

Answer (score 0):

This PHP library has an option to send via notification key:

https://github.com/CoreProc/gcm-php

```
$gcmClient = new GcmClient('your-gcm-api-key-here');
$message = new Message($gcmClient);
$message->setNotificationKey('xxxxxxxxxx');
$message->setData([
    'title' => 'Sample Push Notification',
    'message' => 'This is a test push notification using Google Cloud Messaging'
]);
$message->send()
```