# Not able to send notification to a group using notification_key even though it is possible through the regId

Tags: php, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I made some php code and I was able to send notifications to devices using the regId.

I also managed to create a group of regId successfully receiving the notification_key as describe on the [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#gen-server).

But I'm not able to send notifications to the group. I tried to use the same method to send the notification but instead of using the regId I am using the notification_key I received from GCM when creating the group, but this approach did not work, it gives me the NotRegistered error.
If i try to register with the same notification_key_name GCM say it is already registered.

I am not sure if I have to send it through another method or if I am doing something wrong.

- When I send the notifications using the regId I receive this message
  from GCM:

  {"multicast_id":517...442,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:140...ecd"},{"message_id":"0:140...ecd"}]}
- When I create the group I receive this message from GCM:

  {"notification_key":"APA91....nz9Q"}
- When I try to send the message to the group using the notification_key i received on the message above I receive this message from GCM:

  {"multicast_id":80...63,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
- When I try to create the group again with the same notification_key_name  I receive this message from GCM:

  {"error":"notification_key already exists"}

Below is the code I am using.

```
<?php

class GCM {
 const GOOGLE_API_KEY= " *** MY API KEY ***"; // Place your Google API Key
 const PROJECT_KEY= " *** MY PROJECT KEY ***";


function __construct() {

}

/**
 * Sending Push Notification
 */
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . self::GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}

public function requestNotificationKeyFromGCM($registatoin_ids, $username) {
    //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification';
    $request = array(
        'operation' => 'create',
        'notification_key_name' => $username,
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    );    

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . self::GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'project_id: ' . self::PROJECT_KEY,
        'content-type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues while trying to send a gcm's with notification key. There is an issue in the documentation.
Instead of using:

```
curl -vvv -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "project_id: <YOUR-PROJECT-ID>" --header "Authorization: key=<YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET-KEY>" --data @- "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" << EOF
{ 
   "registration_ids": ["<REGISTRATION-ID-FROM-DEVICE>"],
   "data": {},
}
EOF
```

You have to use:

```
curl -vvv -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "project_id: <YOUR-PROJECT-ID>" --header "Authorization: key=<YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET-KEY>" --data @- "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" << EOF
{ 
   "to": "<NOTIFICATION-ID>",
   "data": {},
}
EOF
```

You can see more in my blog post: https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/d7df385b0ff4

Answer (score 2):

I followed the documentation from [Google's Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/device-group)
(I'm pushing to both iOS and Android).

```
{
  "to": "your_token_ID",
  "data": {
    "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!",
  }
}
```

But it's not working so I tried:

```
{
  "to": "your_token_ID", 
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "gcmSandbox": "true",
    "badge": 1,
    "title" : "Push Title",
    "body": "Push Body"
  }
}
```

This method is working for me, hope it helps somebody else.